# Use values from HTML input

Tags: javascript, html

```
<label for="fullname" name="identity">Name, Surname</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="info" value="" />
```

Once user types inside it something, I want save that into variable. Later be able to use that elsewhere.

```
<input type="submit" value="send" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

What function to create and what to do to to use this value?

Comment: use `document.getElementById`  and get value. This will help https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Comment: Study some tutorials on how to use javascript and forms. Stackoverflow is not a *"how to"* tutorial service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the data on the same page, then you will be able to use vanilla JavaScript by declaring a variable at the document level scope. Here is a quick example of that:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("my_form").onsubmit = my_form_submit;
}

var fullname;
function my_form_submit(e) {
  // Stop the form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();

  // Store the value
  fullname = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
}
```

```html
<form id="my_form">
  <label for="fullname" name="identity">Name, Surname</label><br/>
  <input type="text" name="info" value="" id="fullname" />
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

If you want the data to persist across pages, then you'll need to use a server-side language to create cookies. In PHP you'd establish a session and then set the session variable. Here is a quick example of that:

```
<?php
// Set session variables
session_start();

// Assign the session variable from the form's post
$_SESSION["fullname"] = "info";
?>
```